# Use of double pointers and memory allocation/deallocation

Tags: c, memory-management

I've made an associative array data structure (more details in the code comments below). What I'm interested in getting a critique on is the usage of double pointers.

1. Are they necessary here?
2. Am I allocating and freeing the memory correctly?

`assoc_array.h`

```c
#ifndef __ASSOC_ARRAY_H__
#define __ASSOC_ARRAY_H__

/*
 * A data structure to map characters
 * to integer values.
 *
 * The value always starts at 0, and
 * can be incremented from there.
 *
 * There's a space/speed trade-off based on
 * the `size` provided. A character, `c`, will be
 * inserted according to `c % size`. When more
 * than one character maps to the same "bucket",
 * a linear search is used to differentiate between
 * those characters.
 *
 */

typedef struct AssocArray AssocArray;

/*
 * Create an array of N (size) buckets.
 */
AssocArray *aaAlloc(size_t size);

void aaFree(AssocArray *assoc_array);

/*
 * Increment or set to 0 for the given character.
 * Return -1 if an error occurs.
 */
int aaIncValue(AssocArray *assoc_array, char key);

#endif
```

`assoc_array.c`

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "assoc_array.h"

typedef struct AssocArrayItem {
  char key;
  int value;
} AssocArrayItem;

typedef struct AssocArrayBucket {
  size_t size;
  AssocArrayItem **items;
} AssocArrayBucket;

typedef struct AssocArray {
  size_t size;
  AssocArrayBucket **buckets;
} AssocArray;

AssocArray *aaAlloc(size_t size) {
  AssocArray *aa = malloc(sizeof(AssocArray));

  aa->size = size;
  aa->buckets = calloc(aa->size, sizeof(AssocArrayBucket *));

  for (int i = 0; i < aa->size; i++) {
    aa->buckets[i] = malloc(sizeof(AssocArrayBucket));
    aa->buckets[i]->size = 0;
    aa->buckets[i]->items = NULL;
  }

  return aa;
}

void aaFree(AssocArray *assoc_array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < assoc_array->size; i++) {
    size_t bucket_size = assoc_array->buckets[i]->size;

    for (int j = 0; j < bucket_size; j++) {
      if (assoc_array->buckets[i] != NULL &&
          assoc_array->buckets[i]->items[j] != NULL) {
        free(assoc_array->buckets[i]->items[j]);
      }
    }

    if (assoc_array->buckets[i] != NULL) {
      if (assoc_array->buckets[i]->items != NULL) {
        free(assoc_array->buckets[i]->items);
      }
      free(assoc_array->buckets[i]);
    }
  }

  if (assoc_array->buckets != NULL) {
    free(assoc_array->buckets);
  }

  if (assoc_array != NULL) {
    free(assoc_array);
  }
}

int aaIncValue(AssocArray *assoc_array, char key) {
  unsigned int idx = key % assoc_array->size;
  AssocArrayBucket *bucket = assoc_array->buckets[idx];

  if (bucket == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  int incremented_value;

  if (bucket->size == 0) {
    bucket->size = 1;
    bucket->items = calloc(bucket->size, sizeof(AssocArrayItem *));

    bucket->items[0] = malloc(sizeof(AssocArrayItem));
    bucket->items[0]->key = key;
    bucket->items[0]->value = 1;

    incremented_value = bucket->items[0]->value;
  } else {
    bool exists = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < bucket->size; i++) {
      if (bucket->items[i]->key == key) {
        exists = true;
        bucket->items[i]->value++;
        incremented_value = bucket->items[i]->value;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (exists == false) {
      bucket->items = realloc(bucket->items, bucket->size + 1);
      bucket->items[bucket->size] = malloc(sizeof(AssocArrayItem));
      bucket->items[bucket->size]->key = key;
      bucket->items[bucket->size]->value = 1;

      incremented_value = bucket->items[bucket->size]->value;
      bucket->size++;
    }
  }

  return incremented_value;
}
```

`assoc_array_test.c`

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "assoc_array.h"

void printPass() {
  if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
    printf("\e[32mPASS\e[0m\n");
  } else {
    printf("PASS\n");
  }
}

void test1() {
  printf("[TEST] Characters that end up in the same bucket inc'd correctly\t");

  AssocArray *aa = aaAlloc(26);
  // 'm' % 26 == 5
  // 'S' % 26 == 5
  assert(aaIncValue(aa, 'm') == 1);
  assert(aaIncValue(aa, 'm') == 2);
  assert(aaIncValue(aa, 'S') == 1);
  assert(aaIncValue(aa, 'm') == 3);
  assert(aaIncValue(aa, 'S') == 2);
  aaFree(aa);

  printPass();
}

int main() {
  printf("\n");

  test1();

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
clang -g -Wall assoc_array.c assoc_array_test.c -o assoc_array_test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Allocating.

  - The functions of `*alloc` family may fail. Always test their return values.
  - `bucket->items = realloc(bucket->items, bucket->size + 1);` is plain wrong. It allocates only `bucket->size + 1` *bytes*. You need `(bucket->size + 1) * sizeof(AssocArrayItem *)` of them.
- Freeing.

  A test for `assoc_array != NULL` happens too late. A test for `assoc_array->buckets != NULL` is also too late. You shall test *before* use, not after.
- Using double pointers is not justified. `aaAlloc` allocates that many pointers to buckets, and also that many buckets. It is a pure waste of space. Similarly, there is no reason to separately allocate pointers to items, and items themselves.
- `aaIncValue` looks clumsy. There is no need to single out the case of `bucket->size == 0`. What *is* important is whether the key is found or not, and `bucket->size == 0` guarantees that the key is *not* found. So, consider

  ```
    AssocArrayItem * item = aaFindItemInBucket(bucket, key);
    if (item == NULL) {
        bucket = extend_bucket(bucket);
        item = bucket[bucket->size - 1];
        item->key = key;
    }
    item->value += 1;
  ```

  Also, it looks like a misnomer (should be `aaPut` or `aaInsert`).
- As a side note, `size` is not a best name.Consider `n_items` and `n_buckets`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your feedback. I knew it felt odd doing so much allocation. I'm excited to update it soon. Nice catch on the realloc too.

Comment: To anyone interested, I've refactored the code, which you can find here https://gist.github.com/denvaar/baf6f6f75bff61f5d18442ba656aaccc